# How do I add a style (or class?) to <b> in an external stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, colors

So for example I want to bold a bunch of words but I want "Group A" words to be blue, "Group B" words to be red AND "Group C" words to be green.

However, if I want to go back and change "Group A" words to be orange instead, I don't want to have to go back through all of those words and change the color from blue to orange.

How do I format this in an external stylesheet so I can change all the "Group A" bold letters to a different color?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use class. Include this in the head section to load external style sheet.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

style.css (You can use font-weight: bold; in .groupA to replace the b tag.)

```
  .groupA {
    color: blue;
  }

  .groupB {
    color: red;
  }

  .groupC {
    color: green;
  }
```

HTML

```
  <p class="groupA"><b>Group A</b></p>
  <p class="groupB">Group B</p>
  <p class="groupA"><b>Group A</b></p>
  <p class="groupA"><b>Group A</b></p>
  <p class="groupC">Group C</p>
  <p class="groupB">Group B</p>
  <p class="groupC">Group C</p>
```